# Import BootstrapVue's styles as separate CSS files in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I have generated a Nuxt.js and checked the BootstrapVue option in the CLI. When I run `npm run build` and then `npm start`, when I check the source code there is a huge junk of `<style>` code which is for BootstrapVue. How can I put it in a separate CSS file?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. You could just include a link to an external .css file in your main style section, but then you can't override all the scss variables to change colors, etc. Please post an answer if you find one.